# Heredoc in subfunction in exported function fails

Tags: bash, here-document

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    gen() {
        cat <<EOF
bar
EOF
        true
    }
    gen
}

foo
export -f foo
bash -c foo
```

This fails in the very last line:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    gen() {
        cat <<EOF
bar
EOF
    }
    gen
}

foo
export -f foo
bash -c foo
```

giving:

```
bar
bash: foo: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: error importing function definition for `foo'
bash: foo: command not found
```

Why is the last `true` needed?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Using `foo` without `true`: If you add `export -f gen` to `foo` ; then run `foo ; bash -c gen`, you'll have `bar bar` (with newline) as output. However running `foo ; export -f foo ; bash -c gen` will return `bar <error message> bar` (with newlines). So something about the export seems problematic.... but not for `gen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, apparently first reported in July 2019, see:

- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-06/msg00063.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-07/msg00002.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00014.html

There's also a question on SO with a very similar test case (linked to from the last mail above): [Exporting a function with a nested function definition and heredoc in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564674/exporting-a-function-with-a-nested-function-definition-and-heredoc-in-bash)

The CHANGES file lists this between bash-5.0-release and bash-5.1-alpha:

```
ll. Fixed a bug with printing function definitions containing here documents.
```

As far as I tested, your test case works in Bash 4.4 and in the current git version.

---

What I found curious here, is that if you look at `declare -p -f foo` after the function is defined, you'll see the here-doc has been punted outside `gen`, which doesn't happen if the `true` is there. Looks like it messes up something there. This is the working version:

```
$ declare -p -f foo
foo () 
{ 
    function gen () 
    { 
        cat 
    } <<EOF
bar
EOF

    gen
}
```

And this is the broken one:

```
$ declare -p -f foo
foo ()
{   
    function gen ()
    {   
        cat <<EOF
    }
bar
EOF 

    gen
}
```

Note the `<< EOF` redirection is in the wrong place wrt. the closing `}`. The git version looks to put the redirection where it was actually placed, the same as Ksh and Zsh do.